# not all arguments converted during string formatting MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, typeerror

Keep getting typerror for string formatting, any help would be appreciated, here is my code.

```
db, cursor = db_set(request)
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO my_line(lined_up) VALUES(%s)''' (lined))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: You need a comma to make `(lined,)` a tuple.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770914/mysql-python-connector-not-all-arguments-converted-during-bytes-formatting